# need to JSON output?

Tags: java, json

Here i'm creating one product list in java. I need product list as JSON. How to do this ?

```
private List<ProductFromServiceTemp> getListFromWebservice() 
    {

        List<ProductFromServiceTemp> productList = new ArrayList<ProductFromServiceTemp>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ProductFromServiceTemp product = new ProductFromServiceTemp();
            product.setName("name " + i);
            product.setDescription("desc " + i);
            product.setPrice(i * 100d);
            productList.add(product);
            System.out.println("Product = " + product);
            System.out.println("productList = " + productList);
        }

        return productList;
    }
```

So now it like this

```
`Array ar = [prod1, prod2];`
```

then

```
ar[i].name
ar[i].price
```

how to get the product detail? please any one help me.

Comment: Are you stuck using a particular JSON library, or do you get to use any library you see fit?

Comment: Your question is to vague. Which JSON technology are you using? There are lots of libraries out there.

Comment: i want to parse the product list in java into JSON ? say how to parse?

Comment: *"i want to parse the product list in java into JSON ?"* - That is a nonsensical statement.  I think you probably mean "convert" rather than "parse".

Comment: @selladurai There is no single solution for generating JSON in Java.  Java SE does not have a built-in library to generate JSON.  (The platform you're using might have such a library available.  For example, Android has a built-in JSON library.)  While you could manually build JSON output without a JSON library, it's usually way easier to an API designed to provide this facility.  So, do you get to choose any library you see fit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend that you to have a look at GSon. => http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

GSon is a Java Library that converts Java objects into JSON objects. ;)

I discovered it yesterday. It's great; quick and efficient.

Comment: +1 I've recently incorporated gson into my project... it rocks

Answer (score 2):

If you get to pick any JSON library you like, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) is a decent choice.

Following is a demo of Jackson in action to solve the problem originally presented.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonDemo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<ProductFromServiceTemp> products = getListFromWebservice();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(products);
    System.out.println(json);
  }

  private static List<ProductFromServiceTemp> getListFromWebservice()
  {
    List<ProductFromServiceTemp> productList = new ArrayList<ProductFromServiceTemp>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      ProductFromServiceTemp product = new ProductFromServiceTemp();
      product.setName("name " + i);
      product.setDescription("desc " + i);
      product.setPrice(i * 100d);
      productList.add(product);
    }
    return productList;
  }
}

class ProductFromServiceTemp
{
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private double price; // Don't use double type for financial information.

  public String getName() {return name;}
  public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
  public String getDescription() {return description;}
  public void setDescription(String description) {this.description = description;}
  public double getPrice() {return price;}
  public void setPrice(double price) {this.price = price;}
}
```

The JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name 0",
        "description": "desc 0",
        "price": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "name 1",
        "description": "desc 1",
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "name": "name 2",
        "description": "desc 2",
        "price": 200
    },
    {
        "name": "name 3",
        "description": "desc 3",
        "price": 300
    },
    {
        "name": "name 4",
        "description": "desc 4",
        "price": 400
    },
    {
        "name": "name 5",
        "description": "desc 5",
        "price": 500
    },
    {
        "name": "name 6",
        "description": "desc 6",
        "price": 600
    },
    {
        "name": "name 7",
        "description": "desc 7",
        "price": 700
    },
    {
        "name": "name 8",
        "description": "desc 8",
        "price": 800
    },
    {
        "name": "name 9",
        "description": "desc 9",
        "price": 900
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, ranging from simple JSON object libraries to technologies that support bidirectional mappings.

Take a look at http://json.org for a list of the options available to you.  (There are 21 entries for Java ... which is **way too many** to try to summarize here.)